# не коректно копирует cp

Tags: linux

И так.До этого момента копировал восновном небольшие файлы. Примерно до 300мб. Столкнулся с проблемой, когда начал копировать через `cp` файл образа windows. он весит под 5гигов (4 с хвостиком). Один раз вышло так, что скопировалось порядка 1гига и операция закончилась. Попробывал запустить еще раз копирование, но перед этим удалил файл который был скопирова не точно. Стало, чуть лучше. Образ начал занимать почти 3 гиг. А если копировать через Dolphin (могу ошибатся в названии), файловый менеджер в KDE, все нормально. Есть один нюанс, копировал в папку. которая находится в домашнем каталоге, но в неё примонтирован 1 раздел с другого жесткого диска. Немного гугла, мне подсказало что есть аналог rsync. Может кто то с таким сталкивался?

Comment: Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @вася говорю. Скачал образ винды. он весит чуть больше 4 гигов. командой cp что куда копируется не весь файл

Comment: много вариантов. От просто бага в cp или то, что диск уходит в спячку до бага в файловой системе. А может просто буфера не хватает. Я бы попробовал скопировать через mc. В любом случае, когда "операция завершилась", хорошо бы посмотреть в dmesg - там могут быть очень интересные вещи.

Comment: @KoVadim вот это уже куда интереснее. То есть что ср что rsync это одно и тоже. Хорошо, на будущие учту

Comment: cp и rsync хоть и похожи, но это немного разные программы.

Comment: Скажите, а Вы в реальной ОС работает, или в виртуалке? И какой дистрибутив используете? Если в реальной убунте, то можно выполнить две команды: 1) tail -f /var/log/messages & 2) cp <винда старая> <винда новая> Знак амперсенда в конце первой строки - нужен! И посмотреть, что появится в логе во время копирования.

Comment: ну так я собственно это и предложил - смотреть в dmesg

Comment: Может, FAT/VFAT?

Comment: А что даст фат?

Comment: @Максим ограничение на максимальный размер файла

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev а почему тоггда 2 раза копировалась и получалось скопировать разный размер? И где указанно про ограничение по размеру копируемого содержимого

Comment: @Максим ну я ж не видел, что могу сказать? Вы хоть бы скриншоты показали с `cp` и `ls -l` до и после... Про ограничение указано в спецификациях VFAT.

Answer (score 0):

Программа CP, к сожалению, не выводит результат своей работы.

Используйте rsync с ключами -av (более детально [здесь](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=rsync&category=1&russian=0)).

Пример: `rsync -av /home/user1/MyISO /home/user2/`

Вполне вероятно, что этим методом вы решите свою проблему. Успехов.